# jboss- Missing classpath entry

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss

In Eclipse, I'm trying to create a new 'dynamic web project' by going to New->dynamic web project. As I start entering the Project Name, I get the following error: 
Runtime "JBoss v5.0" is invalid. Missing classpath entry C:\Program Files\JBoss\bin\run.jar

Snapshot:
[image]

I'm using JBoss version 5.1.0-GA. Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you added JBoss runtime in Eclise preferences -> Runtime Environment ?

Comment: Did you configure the JBoss Runtime in Eclipse correclty?

Comment: Ya I did that already....

Comment: I found the following link useful(served as an answer to my question):
http://myblogmchopker.blogspot.in/2013/09/a-helloworld-servlet-in-jboss-eap-6.html

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced this issue and solved it as below:

You have to perform the following steps:
1. Go to Eclipse --> Help -->Install new software-->http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/"your eclipse version"/
---> JBoss Web and Java EE Development ---> `JBossAS Tools` ----> next ---> next ---> accept ---> finish

Once this is done restart your eclipse once.
Then go in the below path:

Eclipse-->Window --> preferences --> server ---> runtime environments ---> add --> jboss community ---> select jboss runtime > next > Where your jboss is located > where your jdk is located > finish

Hope it solves your problem!!!

Comment: As I select 'JBossAS Tools' and select next, I get the following message:
  
Software being installed: JBossAS Tools 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129)
  
Missing requirement: JBoss AS Core Plug-in 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug 3.8.100' but it could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran into this using JBoss 4.2 (I know, I know) and Eclipse Neon.3.

On two different occasions the fix was to go to Window > Preferences > Servers > Runtimes and remove the existing runtime and re-add it pointing to the proper jboss folder. (Not the bin folder, as it adds that automatically, just `C:\...\jboss-4.2.3.GA\`)

Once that is done, you can open the server and set the correct launch configuration and runtime for the server, otherwise every time you try and set the runtime it throws the error specified in the OP questions.